# DB2 z/OS to Oracle/Postgres migration : DB2 Connect replacing

Tags: oracle, db2, db2-connect

In the context of a mainframe rehosting project (from z/OS to Linux), we are planning to migrate DB2 z/OS to Oracle.

Currently, several Windows applications uses DB2 connect DDF/DRDA to access to DB2 z/OS data (through ODBC, JDBC).

Will it be necessary to use Oracle Database Provider for DRDA for these applications ? 
Or can we simply use normal ODBC / JDBC Oracle drivers and adapt the code ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use normal Oracle drivers (if you want your Windows odbc/jdbc applications) to access Oracle on Linux. Yes you may need to adapt some of the code and of course the connection strings. You don't need DB2-connect unless you want some applications to continue to use type-2 drivers to access DB2 on Z/OS.

Comment: Thanks mao. What can be the  added-value of using Oracle Database Provider for DRDA  ?

Comment: That may help if you want your Oracle-apps to talk with legacy DB2 databases, although IBM is unlikely to support any issues with it (but Oracle would support it instead).